# Runtime change in content of Label not resizes properly view when placed label inside a Frame?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created a custom control in Xamarin.Forms for my demo application, in my control I used a custom template for my view, the template consists of Frame --> Grid --> Label whenever I changed the binding text to the labels, the view height should be resized, but it not works as excepted.

If I remove the frame it works fine and height resizes properly. It happens in android, iOS, and UWP.

To notify the size changes in the template, wired the `templateView.Element.MeasureInvalidated` event, it raised properly and resizing working fine for runtime changes if the frame is not included. If the frame included in my data template event is not raised.

Comment: Post the relevant code , which will be helpful to solve the issue .

Comment: I have faced same issue with Xamarin LIstView when using my template in it. 
 https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/5184056/DataTemplate.zip

Comment: It is an expected result . Frame is a subclass of TemplateView , whcih is different from other layout like Grid and StackLayout (the subclass of VisualElement) . You could set the root view of ViewCell as Grid with one row (auto) .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks

Comment: I will post it as answer with more details , could you accept it ? It will help more people with similar issue .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes, Sorry for very late reply